# Driver problems on Laptop

Tags: drivers, wireless, 20.04, touchpad, lenovo

My new laptop, Lenovo V14 iil touchpad and wifi modules are not recognized in ubuntu 20.04 . Please give me solution thanks alot

Comment: 8852 driver? If you dont know, run `lspci` in terminal and post results to question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FIRST:**

Make sure SecureBoot is disabled in the bios settings. To do this, you need to reboot. As the splash screen is loading, you need to press a specific key / button / combo. This varies depending on your model. For V14, I am not sure.

I will let you Google this part yourself, as the result will contain info that you should know if you are going to be performing maintainance tasks in the future. You can use the key-phrase "Lenovo V14 BIOS settings", and the first result should have what you are looking for.

Better yet, a youtube search for "Lenovo V14 SecureBoot" will most likely show the same, along with the location of the SecureBoot. This is where you will need to go. SecureBoot needs to be **disabled**.

**IF SECUREBOOT IS OFF & ISSUE PERSISTS**

You need a working driver. Unfortunately, Ubuntu doesn't provide a driver for this model. However, there is a solution online [here](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89#installation-instruction) which is maintained by the community. More specifically, it is maintained by the developer who built it on his/ her own, so credit is definitely due. Thank you, [lwfinger.](https://github.com/lwfinger)

> The link is to the author's github. If this helps anyone in the future, you now know to whom to pray. XD

**BE SURE TO READ THE ENTIRE README AT THE 1ST LINK.** The process is fairly simple, but there is enough there to mess things up if done just the right wrong way. Take your time and follow the instructions word for word, and you have nothing to worry about. I know from experience that it works.